# What enzymes I shall use for preparing single cell suspension from cardiac tissue for flow cytometry?

Tags: enzymes, flow-cytometry

Can anyone suggest which enzymes I shall use for preparing single cell suspension from cardiac tissue. I will be looking at both cell surface and intracellular antigens involving cardiomyocytes and fibroblasts.